# Correcty parameterized test class fails in JUnit 5

Tags: junit, junit5

I have problem about unit testing using JUnit 5,
namely when I run test method with parameterized annotation it fails but everything is correct, I think. it is JUnit 5 code:

```
@Test
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("data")
public void test(int e){
    System.out.println("e = " + e);
}

private static Stream data(){
    return Stream.of(
        Arguments.of(1),
        Arguments.of(2)
    );
}
```

and it fails:
[image]

, I have tried custom parameterize resolver but there comes up another error: it does not return passed value from data() function, but returns default value what is defined in resolveParameter() function in CustomParameterResolver class. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `@Test` when using `@ParameterizedTest` as this will result in an additional execution of your test. This additional execution expects an `int` to be passed to the test but there is no resolver for this and hence the test fails with the exception you posted.

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("data")
public void test(int e){
    System.out.println("e = " + e);
}

private static Stream data(){
    return Stream.of(
        Arguments.of(1),
        Arguments.of(2)
    );
}
```